# Serait-ce préférable d’employer « sans le vouloir » ou « malgré moi » dans la phrase citée dans les détails?

Tags: reformulation

Contexte fictif.

> Ce fut une surprise pour moi que d’être pris en flagrant délit d’adultère **sans le vouloir** dans un cabinet d’aisance par mon partenaire qui se trouvait par le fait d’un hasard à proximité. Le fait est qu’un jeune homosexuel, poussé par son instinct de chasseur, m’a brutalement tiré dans le cabinet pour ensuite descendre mon pantalon et se livrer à un acte de nature sexuelle. Je n’ai pas cherché à repousser le jeune homme et je me suis prêté au jeu. On ne peut donc pas parler d’une agression sexuelle, étant donné que je me suis laissé faire par complaisance.

> Ce fut l’inattendu pour moi que d’être surpris en flagrant délit d’adultère **malgré moi** dans un cabinet d’aisance par mon partenaire qui se trouvait par le fait d’un hasard à proximité. Le fait est qu’un jeune homosexuel, poussé par son instinct de chasseur, m’a brutalement tiré dans le cabinet pour ensuite descendre mon pantalon et se livrer à un acte de nature sexuelle. Je n’ai pas cherché à repousser le jeune homme et je me suis prêté au jeu. On ne peut donc pas parler d’une agression sexuelle, étant donné que je me suis laissé faire par complaisance.

« malgré moi » et « sans le vouloir » renvoient au délit, qui n’était pas désiré ou consenti. Je veux donc savoir comment vous auriez écrit cette phrase de manière à éviter toute ambiguïté possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dans les deux cas, il n'y a pas de refus explicite ni d'acceptation préalable.
**Sans le vouloir** ou **malgré moi** sont antinomiques avec **je me suis laissé faire.**
Je tempérerais les deux (qui restent équivalents):
**Sans *vraiment* le vouloir**
***Un peu* malgré moi**

Answer (score -1):

Ce fut une surprise pour moi que d’être pris en flagrant délit d’adultère à mon insu dans une cabinet d’aisance par mon partenaire qui se trouvait par le fait d’un hasard à proximité.

Comment: Non, ce n'est pas à son insu. Il ne l'a pas découvert une fois fait, il a été partie prenante ...